# Numerically solving transcendental equation for a range of values

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm trying to solve for corresponding Ef values for a range of T values in the transcendental equation: p = n + Nd.

`hbar = 6.5821*10^-16`

`m0 = 9.109*10^(-31);`

`mn = 1.1;`

`mp = 0.5;`

`ionizeE = 45 *0.001;`

`Eg = 1.11`

`Ed = Eg - ionizeE`

`nd = 10^15*0.01`

`kb = 8.6173*10^-5;`

`p[T] = 2*((mp*kb*T)/(2*\[Pi]*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Exp[Ef/(kb*T)]`

`n[T] = 2*((mn*kb*T)/(2*\[Pi]*hbar^2))^(3/2)*Exp[(Eg - Ef)/(kb*T)]`

`Nd[T] = nd*(1 + Exp[(Ef - Ed)/(kb*T)])`

I attempted to do the following but this clearly doesn't work. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated! Thank you so much.

`f[T_] :=  Ef /. FindRoot[p[T] /. {T -> {50, 1000}} == n[T] /. {T -> {50, 1000}} + Nd[T] /. {T -> {50, 1000}}, {Ef, T}]`

Comment: To numerically solve for `Ef` and `T` you need to provide numeric values for `\[HBar]` and `kb`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for pointing that out, I just tried putting the values for them, but it still gives me the same error. FindRoot::srect: Value T in search specification {Ef,T} is not a number or array of numbers. ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[p[T]/. {Rule[<<2>>]}==n[T]/. {T->{<<2>>}}+Nd[T]/. {T->{50,1000}},{Ef,T}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Comment: Edit your question to include the values.

Comment: @BobHanlon Just did.

Comment: Note that the exact value for `hbar` is `QuantityMagnitude@
  UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "ReducedPlanckConstant"], "SI"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ℏ = 65821*10^-20;
m0 = 9109*10^(-34);
mn = 11/10;
mp = 1/2;
ionizeE = 45/1000;
Eg = 111/100;
Ed = Eg - ionizeE;
nd = 10^13;
kb = 86173*10^-9;

p[T_] = 2*((mp*kb*T)/(2*π*ℏ^2))^(3/2)*Exp[Ef/(kb*T)];

n[T_] = 2*((mn*kb*T)/(2*π*ℏ^2))^(3/2)*Exp[(Eg - Ef)/(kb*T)];

Nd[T_] = nd*(1 + Exp[(Ef - Ed)/(kb*T)]);

eqn = p[T] == n[T] + Nd[T] // Simplify;

sol[T_?NumericQ] := 
 Ef /. FindRoot[eqn, {Ef, 29/50}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

Plot[sol[T], {T, 5, 1000},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!